# WordPress Filepath Link Change

Tags: php, html, wordpress, .htaccess, filepath

Okay. This is a big one, so bear with me.

GoDaddy allows you to create multiple WordPress installations on a single domain. The way I have my clients website set up now is:

```
https://www.DomainName.com/
```

has a WordPress installation on it. I then was tasked with revamping the website. I created another installation on the domain, with a link like:

```
https://www.DomainName.com/togolivejan1
```

Now, keep in mind I have a lot of images and media on the site. If you didn't get the memo from the link, "togolivejan1" means "To Go Live January First" (New year, New website!). Of course I set it live January 1st by redirecting the first link to the second.

This was just a temporary workaround, and I now need to switch the second link to the first link so that the new website (second) is clean and nice and none of the /togolive stuff.

**My Question:**

1. If I switch the first link to another filepath (/archivedlink or something) and switch the second link to the first link, are the images going to populate correctly (not just images, everything on the website)? The reason I ask is because when the webpage calls in items for
   img src ( or others ) and it has https:// link .com/togolivejan1/IMAGE_FILE. When I switch it and get rid of the /togolivejan1 link ONLINE, I'm not sure if it's going to delete the file path on the directory or..?

Comment: The "right" way to do this is to: 1. **Copy** the live site contents into a sub-folder. 2 **Move** all the content FROM `togolivejan1/` to the root folder (where the live site lives).  3. Run [srdb3](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB/blob/master/srdb.class.php) on the database (it's super easy) and do a replace from `www.domainname.com/togolivejan1` to `www.domainname.com`.  4. Go into the dashboard to "Permalinks" and click save.  5. Delete SRDB3, and pull down / remove the contents from togolive and the "backup" folder of the live site.  Then you are done!

Comment: @cale_b - The srdb3 program. I apologize, but how do I run this on a GoDaddy hosted WordPress installation? All it says is: "To use, load the script on your server and point your web browser to it. In some situations, consider using the command line interface version."

Comment: 1. Download the files to your computer, into a folder called "srdb3".  2. Connect to your server via FTP.  3. Transfer the folder to your server via FTP.  4. Browse to the tool by going to "www.domainname.com/srdb3"

Comment: So the website is academyofperformancearts.com. I have edited your instructions. Mind telling me if I have it right? A bit confusing. 
1. Do a backup
2. Move all the content FROM togolivejan1/ to the root folder (where the live site lives). 
- Move wp-includes,admin,content to the /public_html/ directory
3.  Run srdb3 on the database and do a replace from www.academyofperformancearts.com/togolivejan1 to www.academyofperformancearts.com. 
4.  Go into the dashboard to "Permalinks" and click save. @cale_b